# initializing array within class

Tags: java, arrays, class

I am having simple problems initializing this array. I get multiple errors such as ";" expected or identifier expected

what should i do? thanks in advance
my original code is a little bit longer and has drawing methods, but for simplicity i have posted a cut down version which illustrates the problem.
im trying to make a maze.

excuse me if i dont understand how to post the code correctly in this forum sorry guys

```
  public class mazet{

     public static void main(String a[]){

         class square {

             boolean sides[]=new boolean[4];
            private sides[0]=true;
         }

     }}
```

Comment: `private` is an access modifier, if you want to make your `sides` array private, you do that when declaring it - `private boolean[] sides = new boolean[4]`. This creates a `private` array `sides` and sets up all elements to `false`, by default.

Comment: Time for a refresher on Java syntax: Start [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html)

Comment: I don't think StackOverflow is the correct place to start learning Java. There are much better places and courses for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your array declaration but problem in **private sides[0]=true;** you can't start your expression like this, because access modifiers are only allow when you  declaring a member or methods. If you want to make sides as private member field then do like this.

```
EX. private boolean sides[]=new boolean[4];
```

After declaring a member you can't initialise at class level. You can only do this either by using constructor or methods, or do the initialise at the time of declaration.

```
Ex. private boolean sides[]=new boolean[]{true, false, false, false};
```

Or achieve this same thing using constructor or methods.
    **sides[0]=true;**
put this inside a constructor or methods.